# How to repair missing masonry on top of a mantel

Tags: drywall, masonry

There is a hole in the masonry on top of a mantel. This is above a working fireplace. The masonry is attached to a plywood (or sheetrock?). There is a plug on a stud for power for TV. Next to the plug a 3 inch piece of the sheetrock is missing.
How can this be repaired to look reasonable?

Primarily I prefer to patch the hole as it adds to cold draft.

I don't have the missing piece. I have a similar rock. But not cut in the needed size. I can crush it to small pieces, but no control on how nice the pieces look.

I like the plug to be accessible, just in case a TV goes up there. I will probably put a painting there to cover the rough repair. Until a TV covers the area.

Edit

You can get a sheetrock or plywood remnant (you can find some in home improvement stores, or buy a 2 feet piece). Use a hack saw to cut it to 4 inch taller and somewhat wider than the opening. Make a hole in center of visible portion and pass a string in that hole, tie it from the back. Put construction glue on the edges of the piece (2 inch top and 2 inch bottom and as needed on one side). Put the piece in the opening and straighten it and pull on the string to press the glue to back of existing sheetrock.
Give the glue 24 hours to cure.

Check that the glue securely glues the two piece by testing it beforehand.

[image]

Comment: Depends on what you think is reasonable. Do you want rock to cover the hole? Do you have the missing rock piece? Do you plan on keeping the outlet exposed? etc Please add more details thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug with airtight "whatever" and put a picture or other decorative item over it until you decide what to do about a TV.

If you have a piece that looks similar, you can chip away at it until it's about the right size.